# Unable to keep a certain portion from a text and kick out the rest

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Is it possible to create any formula in excel to kick out any certain portion from a string and keep the rest? If I consider this a string `Utopia(UTP)`, my expected output is `UTP`. To be specific: I would like to grab the bracketed portion and strip the rest.

These are the texts I would like to apply formula on:

```
Utopia(UTP)
Euphoria(EUPR)
Ecstasy(ECST)
```

The output I wish to have:

```
UTP
EUPR
ECST
```

Comment: Total lack of research; asked and answered many times.

Comment: Probably you can drop here a link similar to this post @Jeeped.

Comment: I'm not your research assistant.

Comment: So the comment you made earlier is totally baseless huh!!

Comment: No, not at all. When you make any pungent comment, you should provide some credentials in favor of that in order to make your comment valid. That's it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FIND() will identify where a particular character first appears in a string. You can use this to find the parentheses in your text strings. Then plug those numbers into MID to extract the strings you want:

```
=MID(A2,FIND("(",A2)+1,FIND(")",A2)-FIND("(",A2)-1)
```